# IE7 Z-Index issue - Context Menu

Tags: css, internet-explorer-7, z-index, internet-explorer-6

I have the following button with associated context menu

```
    <div class="control-action"> 
        <button>Action</button> 
        <ul style="display:none">
            <li class="action-remove">Remove</li>
            <li class="action-detail">Detail</li>
            <li class="action-assigned">Assign</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

When the button is clicked the associated `ul` shows beneath it as a context menu.

This is working great on all browsers except IE 7. In IE7  the context menu (ul) shows beneath the button below it. I imagine this is likely due to how the stacking context is resolving these elements.

My css currently looks like this:

```
.control-action
{
    position: relative;
    text-align:right;
    width:100px;    
}

.control-action ul
{
    position:absolute;
    z-index: 10000;
    list-style:none;
}
```

Any ideas as to what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have resolved this by changing the element ordering. I have removed the relative position element from containing both my button and menu, and made it only the parent of menu.

```
    <div class="control-action" style="float:right"> 
        <div class="control-action-menu">
            <ul style="display:none">
                <li class="action-remove">Remove</li>
                <li class="action-detail">Detail</li>
                <li class="action-assigned">Assign</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <button>Action</button> 
    </div>
```

With this markup change the css has changed into the following:

```
.control-action
{
    text-align:right;
    width:100px;    
}

.control-action-menu
{
    position:relative;
    z-index:1;
}

.control-action ul
{
    position:absolute;
    z-index: 10000;
    list-style:none;
}
```

Comment: You might want to fix `contol` to `control`. Also, if you ever post another question about IE7 z-index woes, please include a complete test page. It will make the question *far easier* to precisely answer. Anyway, I'm glad you got it sorted.

Answer (score 2):

IE up to IE7 uses the nearest positioned ancestor to determine the stacking context.
You seeing that in IE6 too?

Put your button after the ul and then try it.

Answer (score 2):

IE7 has known bugs with `z-index`.

Without seeing your full page, the best I can do is point you to some resources which explain the issue:

- [IE 6 & IE 7 Z-Index Problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/672228/ie-6-ie-7-z-index-problem/3998006#3998006)
- [IE7 Z-Index Layering Issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1287439/ie7-z-index-problem)
- http://brenelz.com/blog/squish-the-internet-explorer-z-index-bug/
- http://richa.avasthi.name/blogs/tepumpkin/2008/01/11/ie7-lessons-learned/

The idea, in its most basic form, is to test adding/removing `position: relative` and `z-index` on parents of the problematic element until it's fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Could be the `hasLayout` bug.

This may help: [IE7 relative/absolute positioning bug with dynamically modified page content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2473171/ie7-relative-absolute-positioning-bug-with-dynamically-modified-page-content)