# IE-7 Z-index problem

Tags: css, xhtml, internet-explorer-7, z-index

http://www.mimi.clickedsolutions.com/

in above site when selecting option in dropdown box right to search box in header options are going behind the header image or logo in IE-7 
I think it the Z-index problem 
i am facing this problem again and again and didnt get any effiecient solution yet
please suggest me the solutions

Answer (score 0):

I'm on a ferry typing this on my phone, so I can't test your link, but...

In all browsers, z-index is relative to the nearest stacking context.  In FF, Chrome, IE8, stacking context is most often created by having positioning (relative or absolute) and a z-index.  In IE7, only positioning is needed to create a stacking context.

What this means is that in IE7, z-index only applies up to the nearest parent with any position property set.

To make all browsers behave like IE7, for sanity, add "z-index: 1" to any element that also has position set to "relative" or "absolute"

Answer (score 0):

Background information for this bug: [IE7 Z-Index issue - Context Menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6229184/ie7-z-index-issue-context-menu/6229309#6229309)

A solution specifically for your case and the exact way you have your page at the moment:

- On `#header-bar`, add `z-index: 9999` (or whatever number, I just picked that for convenience)
- On `#mainpage`, add `position: relative`.

And here's a live version showing *a version* of the fixes in action, check it out with IE7:

http://jsbin.com/exuko6