# z-index with position absolute vs. IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-7, positioning, z-index

Can someone please help me with this problem i am having with my menu ? 
THe problem is only in IE in compatibility mode. I have the menu with position absolute and z-index 99999999 but still the menu is hidden behond the content. 
Please check :

http://www.tomasdostal.com/projects/modul16/draft2/?page=buildings

Thanks for any advice

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I have the menu with position absolute and z-index 99999999

You need to use an **even higher** `z-index`!

..just kidding.

IE in compatibility mode = IE7.

IE7 has known bugs with `z-index`, see: [IE7 Z-Index issue - Context Menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6229184/ie7-z-index-issue-context-menu/6229309#6229309)

In this specific instance, one way to fix it is to add `z-index: 1` to the `<div class="grid_3">` that is a parent of your menu.

Comment: yeah i used 99999999 because i found it on net, normally i use no more than 100.... Strangely enough, z-index:1 on grid_3 did the trick! thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Z-index only works with absolute positioning (the element is currently positioned relative to it's parent element). Add the following CSS to .menu_wrap.

```
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left 0;
```