# Internet Explorer 7 CSS Menu positioning

Tags: css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-7, rendering

I have created a menu in HTML and CSS that works in all the major browsers (Chrome, Firefox, IE8+, and Safari).  You can find it here: http://www.calvaryccm.com/MenuTest.aspx

The problem occurs in IE 7.

I have a hover menu using some JS for effect. When I try to render it in IE7 this is what happens:

[image: IE 7 Menu Error]

I need some help figuring out how to position the menu under the text. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure whether you want to use `.block` or `.nav` in the selectors below. I've gone with `.block` because I can see it being applied to the element.

- On `.block ul`, remove `overflow: hidden`.
- On `.block li`, add `position: relative`.
- On `.block ul.nav ul`, add `left: 0`.

You now have the [infamous IE6/7 `z-index` problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6229184/ie7-z-index-issue-context-menu/6229309#6229309):

- To fix it in this case, on `.block ul`, add `position: relative; z-index: 3`.
- `z-index: 3` to be one higher than the `z-index` on `#player-area`.

Answer (score 1):

Also, you don't need to use javascript to add the 'hover' class as you've done.  Just use the `:hover` pseudo selector in CSS:

```
ul.nav > li:hover
```