# IE7 and z-index

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-7, z-index

I'm building a new website and it will be a website with different layers.
For the moment i'm thinking out the structure of my page and how they interact to each other.

For example I will use a person and a door. The person walks through the door. You will see that a piece of the door will be at front and an other piece at the back of the person.

To create this. I use z-index. Because everything moves around I want to set the door element in one div element and the person in another.

Here a code example

```
<div id="container">
        <div id="bg"></div>
        <div id="person" style='width:200px; height:200px; background:#000; position: absolute; z-index: 1;'></div>
        <div id="action" style='width:300px; height:300px; position: absolute; top: 20px; left:20px;'>
            <div id='frontofhouse' style='width:50px; height:50px; background:#FF0; position: absolute; z-index: 3; top: 20px; left:20px;' ></div>
            <div id="actiontwo" style='width:300px; height:300px; background:#F00; position: absolute; top: 0px; left:0px; z-index:0;'></div>
        </div>
</div>
```

Now, the problem is that I have the person (#person) in front. The door (#action) in back. But one element (#frontofhouse) needs to be in the front. 
If you play with the z-index everything will work nice in all browsers. But not in IE7.

Does anyone know a fix for this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IE7 is buggy with `z-index`, see: [IE7 Z-Index issue - Context Menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6229184/ie7-z-index-issue-context-menu/6229309#6229309)

In this case though, it seems to be difficult to fix without a lot of messing around.

Here's a version that *looks the same* (or close enough) in IE7 and modern browsers.

http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/ddXEA/

```
<div id="container" style="position:relative">
    <div id="bg"></div>
    <div id="person" style='width:200px; height:200px; background:#000; position: absolute; z-index: 1;'></div>
    <div id="action" style='width:300px; height:300px;'>
        <div id='frontofhouse' style='width:50px; height:50px; background:#FF0; position: absolute; z-index: 3; top: 30px; left:30px;' ></div>
        <div id="actiontwo" style='width:300px; height:300px; background:#F00; position: absolute; top: 10px; left:10px; z-index:0;'></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

would be much easier if you created some jsfiddle. Try adding `z-index: 3` for an #action element

Comment: like @kst said, position relative should help, but if you still need to have this positioned absolute, try setting #container relative and z-index: 1 Can't check it on real IE7 so it is just suggestions

Answer (score 0):

I found this [solution](http://www.shawnpreisz.com/css/z-index-internet-explorer-7-ie7). Try with ***position:relative***.

Answer (score 0):

You can fix that problem by remove 'action' div and adjust top, left of frontofhouse, actiontwo. Following is example:

```
<div id="container">
        <div id="bg"></div>
        <div id="person" style='width:200px; height:200px; background:#000; position: absolute; z-index: 4;'></div>
        <div id="action" style='width:300px; height:300px; position: absolute; top: 20px; left:20px;'>
            <div id='frontofhouse' style='width:50px; height:50px; background:#FF0; position: absolute; z-index: 5; top: 20px; left:20px;' ></div>
            <div id="actiontwo" style='width:300px; height:300px; background:#F00; position: absolute; top: 0px; left:0px; z-index:0;'></div>
        </div>
</div>
<div id="container2" style="position: absolute; top: 350px;">
        <div id="bg2"></div>
        <div id="person2" style='width:200px; height:200px; background:#000; position: absolute; z-index: 4; top: 0px; left: 0px;'></div>
        <div id='frontofhouse2' style='width:50px; height:50px; background:#FF0; position: absolute; z-index: 5; top: 40px; left:40px;' ></div>
        <div id="actiontwo2" style='width:300px; height:300px; background:#F00; position: absolute; top: 20px; left: 20px; z-index:0;'></div>
</div>
```

Comment: But if you want to move the #action element. You now need to move 2 elements and that's something I don't want to do