# css / jQuery overlay div over the multiple li ie7

Tags: jquery, css

Here is the code: http://jsfiddle.net/pfaUZ/5/

When I click li the pop div showing fully overlaying two li (exmpl: li width 100px, pop width 200px;) but if u test in ie7 its not working:

see: [image]

Comment: It is most likely an issue caused by the use of your z-index

Comment: You have a small typo in your demo: `heigth: 100px;`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**See:** http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/pfaUZ/11/

You can fix [this IE7 bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6229184/ie7-z-index-issue-context-menu/6229309#6229309) by ensuring that only the "active" `li` has `position: relative`:

```js
$('li').click(function() {
    $('.pop').hide();
    $(this).find('.pop').show();

    $('li').css('position', 'static');
    $(this).css('position', 'relative');
});
```

I also changed to [`.hide()`](http://api.jquery.com/hide/) and [`.show()`](http://api.jquery.com/show/). Those methods are equivalent to what you were using.

There *might* be a pure CSS fix, which would be more desirable, but I can't find it.

Answer (score 0):

Try like that

```
$('li').click(function() {
    $(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
});
```

and use active css instead of working with 2 elems.
preview here: http://jsfiddle.net/acrashik/pfaUZ/9/

Answer (score 0):

In your `.pop` class simply set the width to 100, it solves the issue:

```
.pop {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px; /* <-- this one */
    background: #333;
    z-index: 9999;
}
```