# PNG and css borders issue

Tags: css, z-index

I've used Inkscape to create a very simple icon in a site I'm developing.  The icon is absolutely positioned over the border of two side-by-side elements.

In Chrome it looks great:-

[image: Chrome]

But in IE7 not so..:-

[image: IE7]

Am I doing something wrong?  There is no transparency in the coloured part of my image, as far as I can tell.

Here's the code I'm using to display the images:-

```
<div class="roadmapstep">
    <div class="roadmapnumber">1</div>
    <h4>Header 1</h4>
    <div class="nextarrow"><img src="nextarrow.png"></div>
</div>

<div class="roadmapstep">
    <div class="roadmapnumber">2</div>
    <h4>Header 2</h4>
    <div class="nextarrow"><img src="nextarrow.png"></div>
</div>
```

CSS for the div containing the image is:-

```
.nextarrow {
    position: absolute;
    top: 65px;
    margin-right: -35px;
    right: 0;
    width: 65px;
    height: 40px;
}
```

CSS for the divs with the border:

```
.roadmapstep {
    width: 220px;
    height: 150px;
    border-left: 1px solid black;
    border-top: 1px solid black;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
}
```

Comment: try to add CSS `z-index:1000;` to element with border and `z-index:1001;` to arrow;

Comment: Please post your HTML and CSS or even better: set up a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) to have your code tested by others. To that looks like something is going wrong in IE with the `z-index`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6229184/ie7-z-index-issue-context-menu/6229309#6229309

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add  `z-index:1000;` to `.nextarrow`

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/BtQ8C/)

---

Try giving the different class name to second div and `position:absolute`. it works!!

[**DEMO 2**](http://jsfiddle.net/BtQ8C/14/)

Comment: Finally got it to work.  Many thanks.  Still confused as to why it doesn't work using the original code though...

Comment: That is because IE7 doesnt support z-index with position:relative

Answer (score 3):

Use [z-index](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp) to position an image above another

Comment: If you give the z-index property of the arrow a higher value than the border, it should work. I'll have a look at your code

Comment: I've added the css for the divs with borders.  I have tried different z-indexes but it doesn't work.  Chrome and Firefox operate perfectly, just not IE7..

Comment: It seems your border and the arrow use the same CSS class? give the arrow another class, and give it a higher z-index value than the border

Comment: They don't..  the div containing the border has class 'roadmapstep', and the div containing the image has class 'nextarrow'..

Comment: Ah, I see now, sorry. I think thirtydot gave the answer to your question than.