# Overlapping elements - HTML, CSS

Tags: css, html, internet-explorer-7

My Autocomplete is been overlapped by another Menu DIV (as shown in figure), which has the following CSS.

This occurs only in IE 7 (the most idiotic browser - accoring to me :) ) works fine in IE 8,9, FF etc.

```
#navlevel2 {
    background: url("../images/bg.gif") repeat-x scroll left -59px transparent;
    clear: both;
    height: 30px;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}
<div id="navlevel2">
    <span class="corner"></span>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="/a/b.aspx"  class="selected"><span><strong>Overview</strong></span> </a>
            </li>

            <li>
                <a href="/v/b.aspx"><span><strong> AAA </strong></span> </a>
            </li>

            <li>
                <a href="/c/v.aspx"><span><strong> BBB </strong></span> </a>
            </li>

            <li>
                <a href="/v/h.aspx"><span><strong>CCC </strong></span> </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
</div>
```

[image]

Can anyone suggest what is the problem here ?

Comment: We'll need a complete code example, not just one CSS rule.

Comment: Maybe post the code of the autocomplete as well? Perhaps you need to add a `z-index` to the autocomplete.

Comment: Please post your code. I think your autocomplete is in the same element as your menu thus overlapping each other if you put it outside the said element this should resolve the issue

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6229184/ie7-z-index-issue-context-menu/6229309#6229309

Comment: z-index could be the issue here

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try adding some z-indexes to your #navlevel2 and whatever you call the overlapping element? for example: say #navlevel1 is the dropdown element

```
     #navlevel2 {
            background: url("../images/bg.gif") repeat-x scroll left -59px transparent;
            clear: both;
            height: 30px;
            position: relative;
            width: 100%;
            z-index: 1;

        } 

      #navlevel1 {
            z-index: 200;
         }
```