# Javascript-jquery script works in chrome and firefox but not ie (cross-fade pictures)

Tags: javascript, jquery, image-gallery

Can someone please look at this page and figure our why it isn't looking right in Internet Explorer? It looks fine in Chrome and Firefox but in IE the layout of the photos gets messed up specifically the two photos on the right hand side of the page.

http://waldrondigitaldesigns.com/gallery.html

I am assuming it something with this script but I am no javascript or jquery expert and barely a novice

```
// wrap as a jQuery plugin and pass jQuery in to our anoymous function
(function ($) {
    $.fn.cross = function (options) {
        return this.each(function (i) { 
            // cache the copy of jQuery(this) - the start image
            var $$ = $(this);

            // get the target from the backgroundImage + regexp
            var target = $$.css('backgroundImage').replace(/^url|[\(\)'"]/g, '');

            // nice long chain: wrap img element in span
            $$.wrap('<span style="position: relative;"></span>')
                // change selector to parent - i.e. newly created span
                .parent()
                // prepend a new image inside the span
                .prepend('<img>')
                // change the selector to the newly created image
                .find(':first-child')
                // set the image to the target
                .attr('src', target);

            // the CSS styling of the start image needs to be handled
            // differently for different browsers
            if ($.browser.msie || $.browser.mozilla) {
                $$.css({
                    'position' : 'absolute', 
                    'left' : 0,
                    'background' : '',
                    'top' : this.offsetTop
                });
            } else if ($.browser.opera && $.browser.version < 9.5) {
                // Browser sniffing is bad - however opera < 9.5 has a render bug 
                // so this is required to get around it we can't apply the 'top' : 0 
                // separately because Mozilla strips the style set originally somehow...                    
                $$.css({
                    'position' : 'absolute', 
                    'left' : 0,
                    'background' : '',
                    'top' : "0"
                });
            } else { // Safari
                $$.css({
                    'position' : 'absolute', 
                    'left' : 0,
                    'background' : ''
                });
            }

            // similar effect as single image technique, except using .animate 
            // which will handle the fading up from the right opacity for us
            $$.hover(function () {
                $$.stop().animate({
                    opacity: 0
                }, 450);
            }, function () {
                $$.stop().animate({
                    opacity: 1
                }, 1000);
            });
        });
    };

})(jQuery);

// note that this uses the .bind('load') on the window object, rather than $(document).ready() 
// because .ready() fires before the images have loaded, but we need to fire *after* because
// our code relies on the dimensions of the images already in place.
$(window).bind('load', function () {
    $('img.fade').cross();
});
```

Comment: You may get an answer faster if you describe specifically what is going wrong in IE.

Answer (score 0):

must be the usual bug with positioning in IE. I would recommend reading the first answer from [IE7 relative/absolute positioning bug with dynamically modified page content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2473171/ie7-relative-absolute-positioning-bug-with-dynamically-modified-page-content) and see if that helps solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

try change your code to below, it should fix the photos on your right hand side. =)

```
// the CSS styling of the start image needs to be handled
// differently for different browsers
if ($.browser.msie || $.browser.mozilla) {
    $$.css({
          'position' : 'absolute', 
          'left' : 0,
          'background' : ''
});
```