# IE7 position:relative issue

Tags: internet-explorer, positioning

Please take a look at http://sources.freehosting.bg/home.html using IE7.

You will notice that the position:relative elements are shifted up like this: http://store.picbg.net/pubpic/CC/12/78f69fd1cdb4cc12.PNG

Can somebody help me to fix it?

Comment: have you tried this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2473171/ie7-relative-absolute-positioning-bug-with-dynamically-modified-page-content

Comment: I haven't but now I tried it and it doesn't seem to work. I tried to set explicitly overflow:auto|hidden.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it!

Just had to add position:relative to the parent elements of the shifted ones.