# How to keep centered image in between two <div>'s

Tags: html, internet-explorer, css

I have the following design in which i have an image in between two `<div>`'s. my aim is to keep the image between the two divs.

in this example, I want the main image (400x200) to be in between the green image(`#firstLayer`)  and the gray(background for body). My solution works well in Firefox 16, safari, and Chrome, but doesnt work in IE. In IE the image gets displyed on top of the `#firstLayer`.

here is a [JFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vW9bn/4/) of the problem

and here is the html and css for quick view:

HTML:

```
<body>
<div id="firstLayer">
  <img id="image" class="center" src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/" >
         <div id="mainContent">
          main page content
         </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
body{
 background:gray;  
}
#firstLayer{
    background: url("http://www.enough.de/fileadmin/docimport/images/background-image.png") no-repeat;

    height:500px;
    width:500px;

}
img#image{
 z-index:-1; 
}

.center{
    width: 400px;
    height: 200px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    margin-left: -200px;
    margin-top: -100px;
}
```

What is the Fix for this problem in IE?

Comment: Is this what you wanted to achieve? http://jsfiddle.net/vW9bn/9/

Comment: There is a bug in IE which will ignore z-index if an element is positioned relative or absolute: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2473171/ie7-relative-absolute-positioning-bug-with-dynamically-modified-page-content I would recommend putting "position: relative" on your #firstLayer div to keep that ontop, if that is what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @AndrewPope: Do you understand fully what vineetrok is trying to achieve?

Comment: @AaronBrewer nope, see, ignore the opacity that i added, I just want the image to be in between the body background and the `#firstLayer` in IE

Comment: @AaronBrewer: refer to this http://jsfiddle.net/vW9bn/11/, view it in firefox, i want it to be the same way in IE

Comment: @vineetrok: Ohh... Oh yes, IE has many problems when using Z-Index. You may refer to these links for more help resolving the Z-Index issue: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/fixing-ie-z-index/ and http://brenelz.com/blog/squish-the-internet-explorer-z-index-bug/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding `position:relative;` to your `#firstlayer` div:

```
#firstLayer {
    position: relative;
}
```

This is to do with a bug in IE that will ignore z-index on your image because it is absolutely positioned, adding position relative to the parent div solves this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this.

```
 <div id="firstLayer" style="width:700px;height:700px;text-align:center;">
         <center>   <img id="image" class="center" src="My_Signature.jpg" 
                                   style="width:400px;height:200px;" > </center>
         <div id="mainContent">
          main page content
         </div>
  </div>
```

Hope, it will helps you. Cheers. !!

Answer (score 0):

to center you image you can try 2 options:

1- put your image inside "center" tag.

ex:`<center><img id="image" class="center" src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/" ></center>`

2- use this css class on your image.

```
img.center{ display: block; margin: 0 auto;}
```

Comment: My problem is not centering the image, i've already done that, i want to keep it in between the body and the `#firstLayer` division

Comment: I would also just like to point out that <center> is deprecated HTML and it is far more advisable to use the CSS alternative.